# See all my questions on a single page?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page

In my profile I can see all my questions. However, it is paginated, which makes it difficult to find old questions through either eye-balling or searching. Is there a way to either a) display all my asked questions on a single page, or b) search only my own questions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the help center page for [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), you can add some search operators.

- `user:me` will select only your posts.  Alternatively, you can actually provide your user number.  Your user number is a url parameter when you visit your profile.
- `is:question` will select only posts that are questions

So [a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1308031%20is%3Aquestion) like `user:1308031 is:question` (or when logged in `user:me is:question`) should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to get around the pagination of 50 per page...The ideal would be to get all the questions on a single page...

Comment: I can look into the pagination requests, but you can always go with option `b` and add more search terms to this search.  For example, you could add tags or keywords.

Comment: Use my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247652/one-page-with-all-my-questions-from-all-sites-open-closed-answered/247660#247660) if you can live with the fact that SEDE is only updated once a week.

Comment: @histelheim you can do some janky things with url parameters for custom pagination.  I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: @histelheim I found a way to manipulate url parameters, but couldn't get more than 50 results on a page.  There might be some hard server limit.